# Input and Output with threads

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a console application with two threads. Both threads make output to the console.
This is confusing when one thread wait for an input, while the other thread is writing to the output.

Is there a possibility to split the console; so that thread 1 writes to the left area and thread 2 to the right area of the console?

Comment: The best solution is to not have I/O occurring in multiple threads.

Comment: One of the two only does output, right? If so, you can write to a file which you monitor using `tail -f` in a second terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on a console you can't do both simultaneously.

What you can do is redirect the output to a string or a stream while the first thread is waiting for input, and then output it on the console while processing the input.